# Reference columns in a FOREACH after a JOIN?

Tags: apache-pig

```
A = load 'a.txt' as (id, a1);
B = load 'b.txt as (id, b1);
C = join A by id, B by id;
D = foreach C generate id,a1,b1;
dump D;
```

4th line fails on:
`Invalid field projection. Projected field [id] does not exist in schema`

I tried to change to A.id but then the last line fails on: `ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output.`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

What you are looking for is the ["Disambiguate Operator"](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/basic.html#disambiguate). What you want is `A::id`, not `A.id`.

`A.id` says "there is a **relation/bag** `A` and there is a column called `id` in its schema"

`A::id` says "there is a **record** from `A` and that has a column called `id`"

So, you would do:

```
A = load 'a.txt' as (id, a1);
B = load 'b.txt as (id, b1);
C = join A by id, B by id;
D = foreach C generate A::id,a1,b1;
dump D;
```

---

A dirty alternative:

Just because I'm lazy, and disambiguation gets really weird when you start doing multiple joins one after another: use unique identifiers.

```
A = load 'a.txt' as (ida, a1);
B = load 'b.txt as (idb, b1);
C = join A by ida, B by idb;
D = foreach C generate ida,a1,b1;
dump D;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Adding a link to this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877288/pig-error-1066-after-iterating-through-a-joined-set).

Comment: If I have any doubts what is the name of a field, I just use DESCRIBE. In your case DESCRIBE C; gives us C: {A::id: bytearray,A::a1: bytearray,B::id: bytearray,B::b1: bytearray}. Now you can easily find proper field name.

Comment: Is there any way to access the names of the fields taken from 'A' within the join result dynamically via some sort of introspection? For example, what if I don't know the schema of 'A' until runtime and then I want the resulting projection on line 4 to only include the columns from 'A' and not 'B'? Thanks.