# Apache Pig Sum calculation

Tags: sum, apache-pig

I am trying to calculate the total shares but am receiving an error with the code, what am I missing?

```
grunt> history
```

```
1   stockprice = load 'PG/TutorialA/input/stockprice.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS(Stock:chararray,price:int);

2   investor = load 'PG/TutorialA/input/investor.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS(id:int,first:chararray,last:chararray,stock:chararray,price:int);

3   investor_stockprice = join investor by stock, stockprice by Stock;

4   group_by_lastname = group investor_stockprice by last;
```

```
grunt> sum_of_shares = FOREACH group_by_lastname GENERATE investor_stockprice, SUM(investor_stockprice.price) as Sum;
```

```
1275634 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt  - ERROR 1128: Cannot find field price in investor::id:int,investor::first:chararray,investor::last:chararray,investor::stock:chararray,investor::price:int,stockprice::Stock:chararray,stockprice::price:int
22/10/16 04:23:01 ERROR grunt.Grunt: ERROR 1128: Cannot find field price in investor::id:int,investor::first:chararray,investor::last:chararray,investor::stock:chararray,investor::price:int,stockprice::Stock:chararray,stockprice::price:int
Details at logfile: /mnt/var/log/pig/pig_1665892905780.log
```

[image: Investor]

[image: Stockprices]

Comment: Please add a sample of your csv files to the question

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have added the file, there is not much data.

Comment: As text, please? So we can copy it and reproduce your error. Refer [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

After grouping, all fields are prefixed with their original relations.

If you `\describe investor_stockprice`, you'd see that. Or as the error shows, you have both `stockprice::price` and `investor::price` in `investor_stockprice`, making `.price` ambiguous.

Related question - [Reference columns in a FOREACH after a JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051180/pig-how-to-reference-columns-in-a-foreach-after-a-join)

If you want last name and the sum, I don't think you want the entire `investor_stockprice` in your generate output

Answer (score 0):

I found my error I had two columns with the same name